# Jquery append content to div

Tags: jquery

I load a content to `<div id="wrapper"></div>` via jquery.

```
$('#wrapper').html(data);
```

When the content inserted into wrapper, there is another div with `id="video1"`.

How can I append something to that `id="video1"`

Comment: Strange actually to find this question, have you tried to accomplish your needs? Can you show what you tried an didn't work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('#video1').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

For demo, I have appended **`p`** here.

Comment: is it possible to add using id or class , from html instead of writing html code in javascript

Comment: @codelearner, you may want to look into XSLT to produce HTML output. If you want to push some server-side processing forward to the browser without relying on javscript, you could get some benefit from this. However as Aleksandar has stated in his comment-as-an-answer, this is not exactly a dynamic approach as seems to be requested by the question above.

Answer (score 3):

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNLM4/)

You can find the div by its ID in 'wrapper' after you insert it using [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('#wrapper').html(data).find("#video1").append(<Your Data Here>);
```

Comment: is it possible to add using id or class , from html instead of writing html code in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#wrapper').html(data);
$('#video1').html("new data");
```

Comment: is it possible to add using id or class , from html instead of writing html code in javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('#wrapper').find('#video1').append('thingsYouWant');
```

OR

```
$('#wrapper').html(data);
$('#video1').append('thingsYouWant');
```

you can directly use id selector to get the element after the element is added to the DOM

Comment: is it possible to add using id or class , from html instead of writing html code in javascript

Comment: Can you give an examlple what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely work:

```
$('#wrapper').html(
    $('<div>').attr({'id':'video1'})
);
```

Comment: is it possible to add using id or class , from html instead of writing html code in javascript

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, it is not possible to add something dynamically, e.g. content, to something that is considered static (as to my knowledge, could be wrong).

So, either you write it manually or you make some sort of automatisation...meaning JS for example.

So, the answer would be no, to all those questions/question.

Regards

Comment: It looks like they _are_ using JS, and want help with "automatising" that.

Comment: Hi, @Benjamin. Sorry I didn't state my reply reference, as it was related to severely repeated "is it possible to add using id or class, from HTML instead of writing HTML code in javascript", which resulted in JS solutions, and not to _them_ (for me it was helpful at some point when i searched results, that's why i responded). Peace out

Comment: Ideally you should do this in a comment, but currently you don't have the reputation level to add comments. I'd flag this as something to come back to and restate this as a comment reply once you have earned the reputation to do so.

Comment: Now, this was helpful, thank you very much. Learning in progress here, and reputation I might add. Regards